# Object with field name "setCode" throws => Unknown property "setCode" in result type

Tags: mapstruct

We are using mapstruct to map objects. And in one of the case we have defined the mapping using @Mapping annotation like below:

> @Mapping(source = "glSetCode", target = "setCode")

and we are getting error Unknown property "setCode" in result type.

> Did you mean "null"?

The field setCode exists in the target object. Mapping other fields in the same way doesn't throw error.

We also use lombok and we have both annotation processors in our pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <testSource>1.8</testSource>
                    <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Did try changing the setCode to something else and it worked. But wanted to know the cause for why it is failing since changing field name will have to be updated in multiple mappers/areas.

Comment: Can you share the POJOs where this is happening? If you are using `setCode` as a target your setter should look like `setSetCode` (which is weird IMO)

Comment: you are correct. our field name=setCode and setter=setSetCode

Comment: I'd suggest refactoring your field name as it is not much readable, plus most of IDE's have great refactoring supports, it shouldn't be much of the work. But I'm also curious about that behaviour :D

Comment: we solved the issue by refactoring. thanks.